# Grouping multiple digits prior to a known value

Tags: java, regex

I'm executing this regex code expecting a grouping value of 11, but am getting a 1. Seems like the grouping contains the correct regex for getting one or more digits prior to a known value. I'm sure it is simple, bit I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
String mydata = "P0Y0M0W0DT11H0M0S";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("P.*(\\\\d+)H.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is [`Pattern.compile("(\\d+)H");`](http://ideone.com/iA9QQk)?

Comment: Is `\\\\d+` a typo? It should be `\\d+`.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22101429/3832970).

Comment: Yes, that is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static void main(String a1[]) {
        String mydata = "P0Y0M0W0DT11H0M0S";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("P.*?(\\d+)H.*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

    }
```

Output

```
11
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.*` will try to consume/match as much as possible before the next part is checked. Thus in your regex `P.*(\d+)H.*` the first `.*` will match `0Y0M0W0DT1` since that's as much as can be matched with the group still being able to match a single digit afterwards.

If you make that quantifier lazy/reluctant (i.e. `.*?`), it will try to match as *little* as possible so of the possible matches `0Y0M0W0DT1` and `0Y0M0W0DT` it will select the shorter one and leave all the digits for the group to match.

Thus the regex `P.*?(\d+)H.*` should do what you want.

Additional note: since you're using `Matcher#find()` you'd not need the catch-all-expression `.*` at the end. It would also match any string that contains the character `H` preceeded by at least one digit and a `P` somewhere in front of those digits. So if you want to be more restrictive your regex would need to be enhanced.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the solution.