# Java - Elegant way of parsing date/period?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, duration, period

From the ISO-8601 standards, there are 4 ways of expressing intervals/duration:

1. Start and end, such as "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"
2. Start and duration, such as "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M"
3. Duration and end, such as "P1Y2M10DT2H30M/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"
4. Duration only, such as "P1Y2M10DT2H30M", with additional context information

Using only Java 8 (no Joda, extensions, etc), is there any elegant way of handling cases 1-3?

I'm aware of `Duration.Parse()` and `Period.Parse()`, but I'm wondering if there's an elegant way of handling the 4 cases. For example:

```
String datePeriod = "2016-07-21/P6D";
String twoDates   = "2016-07-21/2016-07-25";

Duration d = Duration.parse(datePeriod); // DateTimeParseException
Duration p = Duration.parse(twoDates); // same
```

My current thought process is pretty sloppy, and I'm 100% sure there's a better way. Something like handling the 4 cases individually with nested try/catch blocks for each case, which seems a bit like an anti-pattern if anything. (Split on `/`, parse first chunk for date, check for errors, parse first chunk for period, parse second chunk for date, check for errors... you get the idea)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

--

Also, the answers at [ISO 8601 Time Interval Parsing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977637/iso-8601-time-interval-parsing-in-java) don't really help me in any way, as the top answer only cares about the `PT...` stuff.

Comment: Off-topic fun fact: This is the 10,000th queston tagged java-8.

Comment: There’s no direct support for this. First, you will have to split your string at the slash, `/`, and parse each half separately. Second, Java has separated the `Period`, the years, months and days, from the `Duration` the hours and minutes, etc. I think I’d look into using both a `Period` and a `Duration` object, probably making sure the `Duration` was less than 24 hours.

Comment: Do start and end necessarily include zone offset information ( as `Z` in your examples)? Asking thinking `2017-06-01T13/2017-06-12T23` would make a fine interval/duration/period (11 days 10 hours).

Comment: To be honest, I haven't entirely delved into extensive ISO-8601 cases (they're borrowed conveniently from Wikipedia). For my current needs, they don't have a timezone, but if there's a solution that would encompass it, then it's all the merrier.

Comment: I have now posted a [new answer at the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622763/2491410) and hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Your case # 1 is handled by the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class of the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that extends the java.time classes. The class can parse and generate that standard format of `instant/instant`.

Comment: Based on my own implementation experiences with parsing instant/moment-intervals, I would say, handling end components with higher-order-elements left out as described in ISO-8601 (i.e. "2017-01-01T14:15Z/31T16:00") is the real hard nut to be cracked. I have not seen any suitable hooks in `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to handle that case but could fortunately use/implement my own parse engine in Time4J (based on `ChronoFormatter`).

Comment: Actually, the [ThreeTen-Extra project](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra) can handle all cases. For cases 1, 2 and 3, you can use the [`Interval.parse` method](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) - the only thing is that it accepts only complete offset dates (so, no locals here). And for case 4, [`PeriodDuration.parse` method](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) can be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no real antipattern to splitting these things up.  Oracle has split the responsibilities of these individual parsers up, and if we want to use them together in this sort of orchestration, it's up to us to ensure that we peel the pieces together again in a sensible fashion.

That said, I have a solution which works with core Java 8, and makes use of `Function` and a few custom classes.  I'll omit the custom beans for brevity as they are fairly basic, as well as the fact that the main lift is done in the `Function`s.

Note that in order to get 'Z' to be recognized as a valid entry, you have to parse with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`.  Also, to ensure that your durations are properly picked up, prepend `"PT"` to the text that would fit in with durations.  A more intelligent way to get that sort of detail from your existing string is an exercise I leave for the reader.

```
Function<String, Range> convertToRange = (dateString) -> {

    String[] dateStringParts = dateString.split("/");
    return new Range(LocalDateTime.parse(dateStringParts[0], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME),
            LocalDateTime.parse(dateStringParts[1], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
};

Function<String, DurationAndDateTime> convertToDurationAndDateTime = (dateString) -> {
    String[] dateStringParts = dateString.split("/");
    String[] durationAndPeriodParts = dateStringParts[1].split("T");
    return new DurationAndDateTime(Period.parse(durationAndPeriodParts[0]),
            Duration.parse("PT" + durationAndPeriodParts[1]),
            LocalDateTime.parse(dateStringParts[0], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
};


Function<String, DurationAndDateTime> convertToDateTimeAndDuration = (dateString) -> {
    String[] dateStringParts = dateString.split("/");
    String[] durationAndPeriodParts = dateStringParts[0].split("T");
    return new DurationAndDateTime(Period.parse(durationAndPeriodParts[0]),
            Duration.parse("PT" + durationAndPeriodParts[1]),
            LocalDateTime.parse(dateStringParts[1], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
};

Function<String, DurationOnly> convertToDurationOnlyRelativeToCurrentTime = (dateString) -> {
    String[] durationAndPeriodParts = dateString.split("T");
    return new DurationOnly(Period.parse(durationAndPeriodParts[0]),
            Duration.parse("PT" + durationAndPeriodParts[1]));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad to solving your problem since it is a good example for introducing the [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) in [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). you can composing functions into a *bigger* and  *powerful* single function. for example:

```
Function<String, Optional<Range<LocalDateTime>>> parser = anyOf(
        both(), //case 1
        starting(), //case 2
        ending(), //case 3
        since(LocalDateTime.now()) //case 4
);

Range<LocalDateTime> range = parser.apply("<INPUT>").orElse(null);

//OR using in stream as below
List<Range<LocalDateTime>> result = Stream.of(
    "<Case 1>", "<Case 2>", "<Case 3>", "<Case 4>"
).map(parser).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).collect(toList());
```

### Let's introduce the code above each step by step

the code below almost applies the most of [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) in OOP. e.g: [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) Design Patterns and .etc.

#### Functions

[factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): the `both` method meet the 1st case as below:

```
static Function<String, Optional<Range<LocalDateTime>>> both() {
    return parsing((first, second) -> new Range<>(
            datetime(first),
            datetime(second)
    ));
}
```

[factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): the `starting` method meet the 2nd case as below:

```
static Function<String, Optional<Range<LocalDateTime>>> starting() {
        return parsing((first, second) -> {
            LocalDateTime start = datetime(first);
            return new Range<>(start, start.plus(amount(second)));
        });
    }
```

[factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): the `ending` method meet the 3rd case as below:

```
static Function<String, Optional<Range<LocalDateTime>>> ending() {
    return parsing((first, second) -> {
        LocalDateTime end = datetime(second);
        return new Range<>(end.minus(amount(first)), end);
    });
}
```

[factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): the `since` method meet the last case as below:

```
static Function<String,Optional<Range<LocalDateTime>>> since(LocalDateTime start) {
    return parsing((amount, __) -> new Range<>(start, start.plus(amount(amount))));
}
```

[composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) : the responsibility of the `anyOf` method is find the satisfied result among the `Function`s as quickly as possible:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
static <T, R> Function<T, Optional<R>>
anyOf(Function<T, Optional<R>>... functions) {
    return it -> Stream.of(functions).map(current -> current.apply(it))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .findFirst().get();
}
```

[adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern): the responsibility of the `parsing` method is create a *parser* for a certain input:

```
static <R> Function<String, Optional<R>> 
parsing(BiFunction<String, String, R> parser) {
    return splitting("/", exceptionally(optional(parser), Optional::empty));
}
```

[proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern): the responsibility of the `exceptionally` method is handling `Exception`s:

```
static <T, U, R> BiFunction<T, U, R>
exceptionally(BiFunction<T, U, R> source, Supplier<R> exceptional) {
    return (first, second) -> {
        try {
            return source.apply(first, second);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return exceptional.get();
        }
    };
}
```

[adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern): the responsibility of the `splitting` method is translates a `BiFunction` to a `Function`:

```
static <R> Function<String, R>
splitting(String regex, BiFunction<String, String, R> source) {
    return value -> {
        String[] parts = value.split(regex);
        return source.apply(parts[0], parts.length == 1 ? "" : parts[1]);
    };
}
```

[adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern): the responsibility of the `optional` method is create an `Optional` for the final result:

```
static <R> BiFunction<String, String, Optional<R>> 
optional(BiFunction<String, String, R> source) {
    return (first, last) -> Optional.of(source.apply(first, last));
}
```

#### [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object):

the `Range` class for saving a ranged thing:

```
final class Range<T> {
    public final T start;
    public final T end;

    public Range(T start, T end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Range)) {
            return false;
        }
        Range<?> that = (Range<?>) o;

        return Objects.equals(start, that.start) && Objects.equals(end, that.end);
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(start) * 31 + Objects.hash(end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s]", start, end);
    }
}
```

#### Utilities

the `datetime` method creates a `LocalDateTime` from a `String`:

```
static LocalDateTime datetime(String datetime) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(
            datetime, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss['Z']")
    );
}
```

the `amount` method creates a `TemporalAmount` that takes both a `Duration` and a `Period` from a `String`:

```
static TemporalAmount amount(String text) {
    return splitting("T", (first, second) -> new TemporalAmount() {
        private Period period= first.isEmpty() ? Period.ZERO : Period.parse(first);
        private Duration duration = second.isEmpty() ? Duration.ZERO
                : Duration.parse(String.format("PT%s", second));

        @Override
        public long get(TemporalUnit unit) {
            return (period.getUnits().contains(unit) ? period.get(unit) : 0) +
                   (duration.getUnits().contains(unit) ? duration.get(unit) : 0);
        }

        @Override
        public List<TemporalUnit> getUnits() {
            return Stream.of(period, duration).map(TemporalAmount::getUnits)
                                              .flatMap(List::stream)
                                              .collect(toList());
        }

        @Override
        public Temporal addTo(Temporal temporal) {
            return period.addTo(duration.addTo(temporal));
        }

        @Override
        public Temporal subtractFrom(Temporal temporal) {
            return period.subtractFrom(duration.subtractFrom(temporal));
        }
    }).apply(text);
}
```

Comment: One remark: We should avoid the term `Interval` for something which is just a combination of `java.time.Period` and `java.time.Duration` (finally another type of duration only). Intervals are anchored on the timeline, i.e. have a fixed start or end, in contrast to durations.

Comment: @MenoHochschild thanks for your feedback, sir. I'm not good at English. how about `Moment`?

Comment: My understanding (although I am also no native English speaker): `Moment` is a point in time (as implemented in my lib Time4J, other people call it `Instant`- like in Java-8-class), `Interval` is a section from start to end on a timeline (what you and other people also call `Range` - like in Guava). The threeten-extra-project has introduced a combination of `Period` and `Duration` as `PeriodDuration` (a pragmatic choice). By the way, I am not the downvoter...

Comment: I wanted to say: If you choose `PeriodDuration` instead of `Interval`as naming then you would follow the conventions of the threeten-extra-project which is guided by the main author of `java.time`-package. However, it should be noted that this combination only covers an incomplete subset of duration features described in the original ISO-8601-paper. Furthermore, ISO-8601 describes a combination of amount/unit-tuples (mixing calendrical and clock-related ones) just as `Duration`. The term `Period` is inherited in Java-8 de facto from Joda-Time and was part of an outdated old ISO-8601-version.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I know how to solve this problem just now. I just use `TemporalAmount` in java.time package. thanks again, sir. I'll fix my answer .

Comment: @MenoHochschild sir, how about it now? I have inlined  the class to avoding introduce a class with confused name.

Comment: "Hey, `_` is forbidden in Java 8's lambda. So make sure we double it to give it even less sense!"

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire because I never used it, so I use 2 `_` underscores. :)

Comment: Well, maybe the fact that you can't write `_` is a strong indicator to not use `__`? If you want your code to have sense, just name it `notUsed`, `ignored`, `skip`, `thisVariableIsNotUsedButAtLeastYouKnowItNow` (even `x` is better than two underscores). `__` (and friends) bears no semantics in Java and it makes the code harder to read because as readers, we see whitespaces. Java isn't Perl, Java isn't Python. Write code not for yourself, but for others. You don't know what the next guy's programming languages luggage is made of.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thanks for your advice. but this is a personal programming convention. I prefer to  `_` but  java don't support, so I double it to achieve my convention.

Comment: Yep, that's what I understood: "personal", exactly.

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for flow control and returning lambdas could be replaced by method references. Rather a matter of taste: Improved readability by simple null checks instead of `Optional::isPresent`.